# Detecting when an elements hits the top of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm looking for some guidance on what I might be able to use in the way of JS/jQuery to help achieve the following:

1. Detect when a paragraph hits a nav bar that is anchored to the top of the view as the user scrolls (eg through a long article)
2. Get access to the first line of the paragraph to iterate through the characters
3. stick that character in the nav if it == a predefined character

Any ideas on a starting point?

Comment: starting point = intersection observer

Answer (score 0):

The "offsetTop" returns the top position of the selected item. When the item reaches a value of "0" from top it performs an action.

The first paragraph in the target element receives a style that fixes it to a position below the navigation. The position from top is taken from the height of the navigation.

*I hope I have been helpful and that this script is a good starting point for you*

**Example 1:**

```js
var topNav = document.getElementById('myTopNav').offsetHeight;

var el = document.getElementById('element_01');
var movEl = el.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function () { myScrollFunction() };

function myScrollFunction() {
    var res = movEl - document.documentElement.scrollTop - topNav;

    if (res <= 0) {
        el.querySelector('p').setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top:'+ topNav +'px;');
    } else {
        el.querySelector('p').removeAttribute('style');
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myTopNav" style="height:30px; background: orangered; position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px;">
    Top Navigation
</div>

<div id="element_01" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <p>
        LINE 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, debitis at ea nulla eligendi doloremque soluta dolorum dolore voluptatem totam ad pariatur. Aliquid corrupti assumenda nam quos quod repellat quo?
    </p>
    <p>
        LINE 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, debitis at ea nulla eligendi doloremque soluta dolorum dolore voluptatem totam ad pariatur. Aliquid corrupti assumenda nam quos quod repellat quo?
    </p>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

**Example 2:**

When the target item reaches the top of the page, it is checked whether it contains "a" tags. If exist, apply the style of the parent element. In this example, the "a" tags are wrapped in a "span" item

```js
var topNav = document.getElementById('myTopNav').offsetHeight;

var el = document.getElementById('element_01');
var movEl = el.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function () { myScrollFunction() };

function myScrollFunction() {
    var res = movEl - document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var a = el.querySelector('p a');
    if (res <= 0 && a) {
        a.parentElement.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top:0px;');
    } else {
        a.parentElement.removeAttribute('style');
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="myTopNav" style="height:30px; background: orangered; position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px;">
    Top Navigation
</div>

<div id="element_01" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <p>
        P TAG LINE 1: <span><a href="#">Link 1</a> | <a href="#">Link 2</a></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, debitis at ea nulla eligendi doloremque soluta dolorum dolore voluptatem totam ad pariatur. Aliquid corrupti assumenda nam quos quod repellat quo?
    </p>
    <p>
        P TAG LINE 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, debitis at ea nulla eligendi doloremque soluta dolorum dolore voluptatem totam ad pariatur. Aliquid corrupti assumenda nam quos quod repellat quo?
    </p>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```